# Moving average for sold items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new in sql so i am working on moving average for out qty. Below is my script Which is not showing my desired Result.

```
select * from (
select transactdatee,itcode,gname,inqty,ItemValue,OutQty,
avg(Itemvalue) over (partition by itcode,gname,inqty order by TransactDatee,inqty asc rows between 2 preceding and current row ) as MovingAvg,
isnull(case when outqty <> 0 then avg(Itemvalue) over (partition by itcode,gname,inqty order by TransactDatee,inqty asc rows between 2 preceding and current row) end,0) Movingaverageforout 
from mak_stockInHandValue
where gname like '%bahria town%'  and itcode = 2983

)a
order by a.transactdatee asc
```

it showing me below results

| transactdatee | itcode | gname | inqty | ItemValue | OutQty | MovingAvg | Movingaverageforout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/03/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 1 | 48000 | 0 | 48000 | 0 |
| 19/03/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 2 | 48000 | 0 | 48000 | 0 |
| 26/03/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 1 | 48000 | 0 | 48000 | 0 |
| 26/03/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 13/04/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 20/04/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 28/04/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Please suggest where i am wrong my moving average for out qty is not showing.

my Desired Result,

| transactdatee | itcode | gname | inqty | ItemValue | OutQty | MovingAvg | Movingaverageforout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/03/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 1 | 48000 | 0 | 48000 | 0 |
| 19/03/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 2 | 48000 | 0 | 48000 | 0 |
| 26/03/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 1 | 48000 | 0 | 48000 | 0 |
| 26/03/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 48000 |
| 13/04/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 48000 |
| 20/04/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 48000 |
| 28/04/2016 | 2983 | Bahria Town | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 48000 |

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Moving Average for outqty !!!!

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: You need to provide the sample data which you are using to produce the result.

Comment: bro i dont know how to create table and insert in them. i am new on sql !

Comment: Maybe start with a tutorial on *that*, then you can create a DB Fiddle. Or perhaps just add the sample data in your question using the formatting tools provided, like you have already.